# Описание через отрицание — термин

Tags: недопустимая-метка, литература, терминология

Подскажите, есть ли какой-то специальный термин для литературной (фольклорной) формулы описания чего-либо через отрицание?
Как то: "ни мал ни велик", "ни рыба ни мясо", "теремок — не низок, не высок" и т. п.

Answer (score 3):

ЛИТОТА
[гр. litotes - простота] - филол. 1) стилистическая фигура, состоящая в усилении значения слова путем двойного отрицания (напр., «небезызвестный»);

2) стилистическая фигура, состоящая в подчеркнутом преуменьшении, уничижении, недоговоренности (напр., «он не блещет умом» ).

Comment: Да, но надо отметить, что приведенные автором примеры не подпадают под эту фигуру.

Comment: Подпадают."теремок - не низок, не высок"" (не низок - «не ниже, чем надо», а не высок — «не выше, чем надо»).  -характеристика через два отрицания ."ни рыба ни мясо" - подчёркнутое уничижение. Литота - преуменьшение, иногда смягчение - используется как эвфемизм. Чтобы не говорить резкое "ничтожество", говорят чуть мягче-"ни рыба ни мясо".

Comment: Поддержу Сергея. Имхо, не подпадает.

Comment: Во-первых, здесь нет двойного отрицания. Т.к. двойное отрицание, это когда вы одно и то же утверждение отрицаете два раза, и получаете тот же смысл (ну почти), что и в исходном утверждении. Во-вторых, двойное отрицание само по себе - отдельный прием, и под понятие литоты подпадает только в косвенных проявлениях, когда возникает эвфемизм. И, в-третьих, литота именно преуменьшение. Но в описанной структуре - смысл не в преуменьшении, а в избегании прямого определения. Все, что есть, описывается без преуменьшений. Просто отсекается то, что не соответствует действительности.

Comment: У Вас не двойное отрицание=положительный результат, а ДВА анафорических отрицания, две литоты.

Comment: Я нигде не упоминала того, что в приведенном мной примере имеется двойное отрицание. Двойное отрицание было упомянуто в определении литоты, которое вы мне привели. Зачем вы тогда запостили эту часть, если, по вашему же мнению, она никакого отношения к делу не имеет?

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю как назвать такие фразы. Однако не согласен, что они описывают ситуации или предметы через отрицание. Ни мал ни велик - описывает обьект, который сложно отнести к маленьким, но и до большого он не дотягивает. Ни рыба ни мясо - что-то непонятное, невразумительное. Теремок не низок, не высок - то же самое.

Answer (score 0):

Пошерстила немного... Наткнулась на такое понятие как

> **Антенантиоз**
>       (греч.) — риторическая фигура, старающаяся отрицанием какого-нибудь понятия обозначить противоположное понятие, напр. "это
>   нехорошо" вместо "это дурно".
>
> Энциклопедический словарь Ф.А. Брокгауза и И.А. Ефрона. — С.-Пб.:
>   Брокгауз-Ефрон. 1890—1907.

К сожалению, расширенных определений и примеров не нашла... Не вполне уверена, подходит ли этот термин...

Comment: Alena,литота иначе называется  антенантиозис или антенантиоз. Это одно и то же.   http://nsportal.ru/shkola/russkiy-yazyk/library/2014/01/28/sredstva-usileniya-vyrazitelnosti-rechi-ponyatie-tropa-vidy  
http://12fan.ru/3120481843.html

Comment: Если Вам нужен термин описания через отрицание , это точно литота. Если нужен термин именно к этим примерам, можно назвать эмфазой-риторическая фигура усиления выразительности, здесь через анафорический повтор. Только эмфаза - это широкое понятие, не обязательно связанное с отрицанием. Или просто назвать фразеологизмом, основанным на отрицании. Я не знаю, что Вам надо.

Comment: литота - это художественный прием. антенантиоз - это логика построения текста. Они не могут быть одним и тем же, они, в принципе, в двух разных плоскостях лежат - как образ, который рисует художник, и краски, которыми он рисует.